# Play an alarm during a call

Tags: android, audio, call

I am creating an application that i have to play a sound. If the phone is ringing or in a call, i want to play the sound in the earphone. The code bellow works perfectly only if the screen is on, but in a call, when i put the phone in my ear, the screen gets off and my "alarm" doesn't play. any hint?

```
TelephonyManager tm =  (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                int state = tm.getCallState(); 
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
                    mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); 
                audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    Log.d("GOFC","Tocando ou fora do gancho");
                } else {
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 1);
                    Log.d("GOFC","Normal");
                }
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if the phone is currently in a call and the screen is on your alarm works but if you are currently in a call and the screen is off it will not work?

Comment: Yes. When i put the phone in my ear my screen turns off(there is a sensor to do that). I can hear the alarm putting my phone on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `WakeLock`. You should listen for events when phone is picked up to acquire `WakeLock` and when phone is hanged to release `WakeLock`.

This is just a wild guess though.

Comment: I tried using WakeLock but it didn't work. Even using WakeLock my screen didn't turn on.